# Python string function parameter replacing

Tags: python, string, function, replace, row

I would like to ask your help. I have started learning python, and there are a task that I can not figure out how to complete. So here it is.

We have a input.txt file containing the next 4 rows:

```
f(x, 3*y) * 54 = 64 / (7 * x) + f(2*x, y-6)

x + f(21*y, x - 32/y) + 4 = f(21 ,y)

86 - f(7 + x*10, y+ 232) = f(12*x-4, 2*y-61)*32 + f(2, x)

65 - 3* y = f(2*y/33 , x + 5)
```

The task is to change the "f" function and its 2 parameters into dividing. There can be any number of spaces between the two parameters. For example f(2, 5) is the same as f(2   ,     5) and should be (2 / 5) with exactly one space before and after the divide mark after the running of the code. Also, if one of the parameters are a multiplification or a divide, the parameter must go into bracket. For example: f(3, 5*7) should become (3 / (5*7)). And there could be any number of function in one row. So the output should look like this:

```
(x / (3*y)) * 54 = 64 / (7 * x) + ((2*x) / (y-6))

x + ((21*y) / (x - 32/y)) + 4 = (21 / y)

86 - ((7 + x*10) / (y+ 232)) = ((12*x-4) / (2*y-61))*32 + (2 / x)

65 - 3* y = ((2*y/33) / (x + 5))
```

I would be very happy if anyone could help me.

Thank you in advance,
David

Comment: Can you give us some code that you've already written in an attempt to solve this problem? What sort of effort have you already made so that we may build on it or point out some errors in logic/syntax?

Comment: I really have no idea how to start with. I started learning python like 1 months ago. I have tried slitting, but that didn't work since the f(a, b) could be anywhere in a row. I tried finding "f(" s but I don't know what next. I don't know the language so well, but trying to get better. My way of solving this would be:

- Finding f(x ,y) shaped strings using joker characters, like searching for f(*,*).
- Somehow give different variable for both sides of the ",". So between "(" and "," is the first variable, and "," to ")" is the second.
- Strip spaces.

Comment: - Check if the two variables has any of the following characters: +, -, /, *. If it has, then we need to enbracket it. - Put it into output with the following format: "(" + variable1 + " / " + variable2 + ")".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html):

```
In [84]: ss=r'f(x, 3*y) * 54 = 64 / (7 * x) + f(2*x, y-6)'

In [85]: re.sub(r'(f\()(.*?),(.*?)(\))', lambda m: '((%s) / (%s))'%(m.group(2), m.group(3)), ss)
Out[85]: '((x) / ( 3*y)) * 54 = 64 / (7 * x) + ((2*x) / ( y-6))'
```

### Explanation:

1. [`re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) returns the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
   non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
   replacement repl.
2. The `()` are used to catch the groups;
3. `*?` is a [non-greedy qualifier](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy), which matches as *little* text as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some places to start:

- You can check if one string is in another string using `string1 in
  string2` (e.g., 'bcd' in 'abcdefg' -> True)
- You can identify the insides of f() calls by finding the locations of 'f(' in a
  string and then adding 1 to an index (that starts at 1) when you find
  a '(' and removing 1 when you find ')'. When you hit 0 you're done.
- You can break a string into a list by a matching string by
  string1.split(string2) (e.g., 'a,b'.split(',') -> ['a', 'b']
- You can format a string easily using the
  [.format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) method
  (e.g., '({0} % {1})'.format(string1, string2))